# How to show some empty item in hightcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have some data in previous hours ,but data after now is null, I want show them just like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add xmax to desired value xAxis.

So that other points will be shown null.
and you can say

startOnTick: false, endOnTick:false

For example refer : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nagoba/dP8cL/1/)

I have values set min of y to 20 and max to 400,

```
yAxis: {
        min: 20,
        max:400,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick:false
    },
```

See how ther chart is displayed. I hope this helps.